# Repaint method when JButton is pressed is not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I am writing this program in where there are 5 panels, and two of the panels, called RightPanel and LeftPanel, are next to each other. The RightPanel, which is a JPanel contains a JButton and a text field. The main problem is with the JButton. Whenever I click the button, which is called 'nose', the LeftPanel, which is another panel right next to the RightPanel, is supposed to paint a yellow oval. When I am trying this, it does not work.

I have tried e.getSouce == nose but it did not work either, so I tried getActionCommand. I know I am supposed to use repaint, and that is what I am trying, but it is not working .

Here is my code.

```
    // SneezePanels.java
/*  IDEA of this program:  PanelHolder, which is added to the frame, holds two panels,
LeftPanel and RightPanel, which are added to PanelHolder in a GridLayout. The 
LeftHolder has a BorderLayout and has two panels-a direction panel, with a FlowLayout 
that has a the button, and a textField panel that contains the textField.  When
the button is pressed, Achoo and a yellow oval are drawn on the Right Panel.  
When the user types in "Bless you" in the textField, the RightPanel is erased
and variables are reset.
*/
/// Testing:  Only clicking on the button will draw on the right panel.  Only typing 
/// in "Bless you" will clear it.
/// Try clicking anywhere other that the button.  This should will not change anything.  
/// Typing anything other than "Bless you" will not reset the panels.

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Color;      
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class SneezePanels
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SneezePanels sp = new SneezePanels();
        sp.run();
    }

    public SneezePanels()
    {   
    }

    public void run()
    {
        JFrame sneezeFrame = new JFrame ("Sneeze and Bless you.");

        sneezeFrame.setSize( 600, 400);             
        sneezeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        sneezeFrame.setLocation(400,50);
        sneezeFrame.setResizable(true);
        PanelHolder pHolder = new PanelHolder(); 
        sneezeFrame.add( pHolder );     
        sneezeFrame.setVisible(true);   
    }

    // This panel holds two panels-one on the left and one on the right, aptly 
    named
class PanelHolder extends JPanel
{
    private RightPanel rp;  // these are field variables so the nested classes have access to them
    private boolean nosePressed;    // otherwise, we have to use getter-setter methods
    private Font font;

    private JButton nose; 
    private JTextArea directions;


    public PanelHolder()
    {
        setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2) );
        nosePressed = false;
        font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);

        LeftPanel lp = new LeftPanel();
        add(lp);
        rp = new RightPanel();
        add( rp );
    }

    // This panel will have a BorderLayout
    //  It will have the directions panel in the center, and the 
    // textField panel in the south. 
    class LeftPanel extends JPanel
    {   
        public LeftPanel()
        {   
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            // setBackground( Color.MAGENTA );

            DirectionPanel dirP = new DirectionPanel ();
            TFPanel tfp = new TFPanel();

            add ( dirP, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            add ( tfp, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        }

    }

    // DirectionPanel will print the directions and contain the 
    // nose button.  It has a FlowLayout.  It will use a 
    // ButtonHandler for actionPerformed.
    class DirectionPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public DirectionPanel()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            nose = new JButton("nose");
            add(nose);

            directions = new JTextArea("Directions: Press button to tickle the nose.");
            add(directions);

            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }   

        public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

        }

    }

    // The TFPanel will have a FlowLayout and contain a text field
    // that will be on the left.  It uses a handler class for 
    // actionPerformed
    class TFPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private JTextField blessYou;

        public TFPanel()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            blessYou = new JTextField("Type: 'Bless you.'");

            add(blessYou);

        }
    }

    // The RightPanel is used to draw "Achoo" and a yellow oval when the
    // button is pressed and cleared when "Bless you" is typed in
    // the textField
    class RightPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public RightPanel()
        {
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if(nosePressed)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 40, 50);
            }

        }

    }

    // When the button is pressed, the method actionPerformed is 
    // used to call paintComponent in RightPanel
    class Button1Handler implements ActionListener 
    {
        public Button1Handler()
        {
            nose.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            String pressed = e.getActionCommand();

            if(pressed.equals("nose"))
            {
                System.out.print("l");
                System.out.println("pressed");
                nosePressed = true;
                rp.repaint();
            }
        }
    }   // end class Button1Handler 

    // When the user types in "Bless you" in the textField, the 
    // boolean is reset and RightPanel's paintComponent is called
    class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

        }
    }   // end class TextFieldHandler
}
}
```

Yes, I have imported everything, even though it might not look like it, I am working on eclipse, it just does not show the import. I expect the output to be that when the button 'nose' is pressed, a yellow oval is painted on the RightPanel. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code is ... interesting.  The short answer is, you never initialise `Button1Handler`, so it's never attached to `nose`'s `actionListener` ... which you shouldn't do, you should create an instance of `Button1Handler` and then add it as a listener to `nose`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the suggestion but I am not sure what you mean by initializing Button1Handler since it is a method. I have tried making an instance of the Button1Handler class and using that as the listener for the JButton 'nose' but there are some errors when I try to do that. I just can't get the button to work for some reason.

Comment: `Button1Handler` is a class - `class Button1Handler`, you MUST instantiate an instance of the class in order for your code to register it against the button

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I do that? Is it just 'new Button1Handler();' ?

Comment: Pretty much.....

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did that but it the button still does not trigger any response. I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Also, where would I instantiate it because right now I am instantiating it in the actionPerformed method.

Comment: The `actionPerformed` is never called because you never instantiating the button handler ... this is why the handler should not be registering itself to the button.  Create the button, create the handler, register the handler to the button - the code will make more sense (and be more reusable) that way